# Can span be constexpr?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20

All the constructors of std::span are declared constexpr, however I can't seem to get any of them to work in a constexpr context. Uncommenting any of the constexpr below will result in a compilation error.

```
#include <array>
#include <span>

int main()
{
    constexpr int carray[3] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    constexpr std::array<int, 3> array{ 0, 1, 2 };
    using S = std::span<const int, 3>;

    /*constexpr*/ S span1{ array.data(), 3 };
    /*constexpr*/ S span2{array.begin(), array.end()};
    /*constexpr*/ S span3{carray};
    /*constexpr*/ S span4{array};
}
```

Is it in fact possible to create a constexpr span type, since it seems like constructors can never be evaluated at compile time when they have to initialize a pointer or reference?

Comment: Uncomment the constexprs don't remove them.

Comment: You are initializing a runtime span I meant to initialize a constexpr span

Comment: Doh.  Not sure why I did that.  nevermind

Comment: weird, don't see why that would be necessary the span only lives inside the local scope anyway...

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57545503/2069064

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use non-static function local variables in a constant expression like that.  You need address stability and that is only achieved by static objects.  Modifying the code to

```
constexpr std::array<int, 3> array{ 0, 1, 2 };
constexpr int carray[3] = { 0, 1, 2 };

int main()
{
    using S = std::span<const int, 3>;

    constexpr S span1{ array.data(), 3 };
    constexpr S span2{array.begin(), array.end()};
    constexpr S span3{carray};
    constexpr S span4{array};
}
```

or

```
int main()
{
    static constexpr std::array<int, 3> array{ 0, 1, 2 };
    static constexpr int carray[3] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    using S = std::span<const int, 3>;

    constexpr S span1{ array.data(), 3 };
    constexpr S span2{array.begin(), array.end()};
    constexpr S span3{carray};
    constexpr S span4{array};
}
```

Allows you to create a `constexpr` `std::span`.

Comment: Scope is not the problem. Storage duration is. Static local should work.

Comment: It also works if all are function local objects within a `constexpr` function (without explicit `static`). Do such objects have default static storage duration or is this something different?

Comment: @n314159 I'm not sure if that is allowed or if you've fallen into the dreaded: if no specialization of a constexpr function is a core constant expression the function is ill-formed, no diagnostic required clause.  [\[expr.const\]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#10) only allows static variables.

Comment: @n314159: I’m not sure exactly what you’re saying works (or “works”), but be careful of the difference between using something as a constant expression **in** a function (constexpr or no) and using something to **construct** a constant expression *via* a constexpr function.

Comment: You might want to say that non-static (constant) *values* can be used in constant expressions, but not their *addresses*.